Logic Apps - Debug why MS Teams Create A Team conenctor works intermittently
I have a Logic App in Azure, that has as a first action "Create a Team" under MS Teams.
The parameters for this are just name, description & private/public(private selected).

Now sometime this works and takes milliseconds, sometimes it just hangs there and never completes(even after hours) with no output. I have tried a retry policy, and a time out policy - neither has any effect.
Clearly since it works some of the time, but not others (about 50/50) - there must be some kind of blocker occurring, so my question is, is there any way to debug this and find out what is going on?

So I have done some more digging, and found that even when it hangs, it still actually creates the Team. But never gets a status returned saying such. The status when polling the operation on Graph is always "notStarted"
